# How can I access a value in an Object[] in an Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, arraylist

I have a List with Object[] inside and I want to access a value of one of the Objects[]. This is how my code looks:

```
private List<Object> trackList;
trackList = new ArrayList<>();

Integer random = (int)(Math.random() * ((100 - 0) + 1)) + 0;
Integer random2 = (int)(Math.random() * ((100 - 0) + 1)) + 0;
Object[] currTrack = new Object[]{random1, random2};
trackList.add(currTrack);

Integer value1 = trackList.get(0)[1];
```

Getting: "Array type expected; found:'java.lang.object'

I think I am missing something very simple. Help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Why not declare `trackList` as `List<int[]>` and `currTrack` as `int[]`?

Comment: 1. You need to type cast. from Object to Integer.

Comment: *"I have a List with Object[] inside"* -> clearly not ... your list does **not** contain `Object[]` or at least it's not type as a list of arrays ... and not using typed arrays and lists, like `int[]` and `List[int[]]` is weird in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you list declaration you set that list is contains of Objects not Object[]:

`List<Object> trackList;`

So when you do:

`trackList.get(0)`  That gets you an Object and not an Object[]

You need to change List initialization to

`List<Object[]> trackList;`

Comment: List<Object[]> trackList; works perfectly and was what I was looking for. Thanks...drove me crazy

Answer (score 5):

You declared your list like this:

```
List<Object> trackList;
```

So when you do:

```
trackList.get(0)
```

That gets you an `Object` and not an `Object[]`.

You need to cast it:

```
((Object[])trackList.get(0))[1]
```

But then you have another problem, cause that expression above returns you an `Object` and you want to assign it to an `Integer`.

So you need another cast.. complete line should be:

```
Integer value1 = (Integer)((Object[])trackList.get(0))[1];
```

By the way, it'd be easier to just declare the list to contain what you'll be actually putting into it.

Comment: As I assumed an simple solution for that mistake. List<Object[]> trackList; works perfectly. Thanks for your help :)